# How to get an element index on a fixed set of elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, indexing, element

I have a fixed set of elements (say 30) in a container. Now when an element is clicked I want to figure out its index in that container.

What I know I can do:

1. set clickhandlers on all the elements with their respective indexes so that when they're clicked they already know their index from the closure scope
   Pros: probably the quickest way
   Cons: more event handlers->more objects->more memory
2. iterate through all of the children, comparing each element to the one clicked and counting the indexes till you reach it
   Pros: works
   Cons: you have to iterate through list and make the comparisons (slower)
3. (Proposed on SO) Use previousSibling attribute to go back to null counting each child along the way to determine your index
   Pros: works, possibly a little better than option 2 since you start straight from the child
   Cons: still iterating through the elements
4. (Solution I thought of) Since there's a fixed set we can set the "tabindex" attribute on each element (in the html or via JS), when the element is clicked we just check the tabindex attribute of the element
   Pros: should be just as fast as option 1
   Cons: (before I'm yelled at for not using the tabindex as it was intended :]) and this makes the elements focusable which you may or may not want

So in terms of performance (speed and memory), which of the above would be the best way or is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks a lot in advance, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You can test such things yourself on http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: And thanks Felix, I did know about this, I just wanted to show the options I had already considered in order to encourage thinking about a different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 5, which is better than all of the above - store the index as a `data-index` attribute on the node, and retrieve that in the event handler.

Rather than having the event handler registered on every node, you can register it on the container and then use "event bubbling".  As the click event isn't handled in the child it'll bubble up through the DOM to the node's parent where you can use `event.target` to find the node that originally received the event.

```
var container = ... // your container;

container.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;    // which child was actually clicked
    var index = target.getAttribute('data-index');
    ...
}, false);
```

On newer browsers you can use `target.dataset.index` instead of the `getAttribute` call.

Comment: Hi Alnitak, definitely wanted to use one event handler at the container level instead of one on every element, that's why I wasn't a fan of option 1. But your solution looks great, it's like option 4 but with none of its cons. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sourceIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for all IE browsers and use [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.previousElementSibling) for other browsers.

Using sourceIndex is simplest and fastest, but IE only.

Setting attribute data-index is not a good solution if the DOM nodes can be changed.

previousElementSibling and previousSibling are not very slow.

```js
function getChildrenIndex(ele){
    //IE is simplest and fastest
    if(ele.sourceIndex){
        return ele.sourceIndex - ele.parentNode.sourceIndex - 1;
    }
    //other browsers
    var i=0;
    while(ele = ele.previousElementSibling){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```